# Issue with C# Websocket and ECDHE ciphers

Tags: java, c#, ssl, tomcat, websocket

First, I am no crypto-expert so what I've been digging into is new territory.

I have a C# client that uses websockets to get information from a web service running in Tomcat.  Our current environment is the following:

Workstations running client - Windows 10 with .NET 4.6.2
Tomcat Server - Windows Server 2016 running Tomcat 9.0.22 and OpenJDK 11.0.2 (though I've tried OpenJDK 13 and same problem)

Tomcat is configured with the following SSL configuration:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
               allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation="false" 
               maxThreads="1000" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
               scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               SSLEnabled="true" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation" 
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
               keystoreType="Windows-ROOT" 
               keystoreFile="Running.txt" 
               ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
                    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
                    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
                    SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
                    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                    SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"/>
```

So our certs are stored in the Windows trust store.

My C# client code using websockets is the following:

```
WebSocketSharp.WebSocket ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket(connectURL);
ws.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
ws.Connect();
```

and I have also tried the base .NET ClientWebSocket:

```
ClientWebSocket newWs = new ClientWebSocket();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                newWs.Options.AddSubProtocol("Tls12");
                try
                {
                    await newWs.ConnectAsync(new Uri(connectURL), CancellationToken.None);
                }
                catch (Exception wse)
                {
                    log.Error("Error in ClientWebSocket: " + wse.Message, wse);
                }
```

Both clients (I believe WebSocketSharp is just a convenient wrapper around the base classes), because of a GPO on all our machines in our environment, are sending only ECDHE/DHE ciphers in the client handshake.

What I end up getting in SSL debug is the following error when trying to "Produced server Certificate handshake message":

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|33|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-2|2019-10-02 16:56:50.058 UTC|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): Failed to sign ecdhe parameters: RSA (
"throwable" : {
  java.security.SignatureException: Keyset does not exist

    at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.RSASignature.signHash(Native Method)
```

The thing is

1. Google Chrome is using the exact same cipher ("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)") and connects perfectly fine
2. Prior to the Windows-ROOT certs we had server certs (that were generated from an external CA) stored in a Java keystore and all of this works fine if I point our Tomcat to that.

So my question is does this have something to do with how our certs are generated (we're now using an internal CA to generate them), perhaps a flag or extension or bit that needs to be flipped?  I was leaning towards that until I found Google Chrome is having no issues with the same cipher.  Though the C# client handshake and the Google Chrome client handshake look quite a bit different (I can post those if that will help).

I would imagine the certificate would have everything configured correctly for ECDHE/DHE handshakes or else Chrome would fail, too.  But the fact that the C# client has no problem with the older certs leads me to believe something in the cert generation is causing a problem.

Or perhaps it's a combo of both?

When I asked our sys admin to add back the following ciphers
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

to the GPO, the clients were able to connect just fine.

We have a couple of people on our program that are fairly confident with cryptography, cert generation, etc but they're a bit stumped so any help on at least where we can look would be great.  I believe we can get a waiver to allow the TLS_RSA ciphers, but since ECDHE/DHE handshakes provide a higher level of security, it would be very nice to figure where the failure is happening and how to fix it.  I just have pretty much exhausted the limits of my knowledge in this area.

Thanks!

Comment: By any chance were you able to solve this issue? I am seeing the same error.